# All other routes aren't working except '/' on my Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I'm a trying to learn the framework Laravel. I installed it and I configured the virtual hosts

When I tried to access the project, it works

but when I tried another root such as /justForTest
it didn't work
I don't know why ?!

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/justForTest', function () {
   //return view('welcome');
   return "Hello world !";
});
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC0Bm.png)

I tried many solutions on the net in vain.
I use kubunto 17.04 and this is what I did

-I added the Directory with **AllowOverride all** on my **lsapp.div.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin ham.elmaslouhi@gmail.com
ServerName lsapp.dev
ServerAlias www.lsapp.dev
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/lsapp/public
     <Directory "/var/www/html/lsapp/public">
     AllowOverride all
     </Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

-I have enabled the rewrite mode with **a2enmod rewrite**

-I added the line **RewriteBase /laravel/** on my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laravel/   
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Thank's for helping me.

Comment: Please add actual code to question instead of pictures of code.

Comment: note that when u try this the url should be:  localhost:8000/justForTest   capital 'F' and 'T' .

Comment: @dsadnick Okey i did it , hope it's clear now

Comment: @L.Kelmendi  it doesn't work

Comment: What does you log say?  Location is storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: Remove or comment

#RewriteBase /laravel/

in your .htacess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove or comment `#RewriteBase /laravel/` in your .htacess